# Python Tkinter not working in a .py file

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is that my python code is not working when I run it as a .py file. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
tk=tkinter.Tk()
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
```

There is more code to it than that, but that is the relevant stuff. It works fine when I use the python shell or type it directly into the python console, but when I run it as a .py file, it seems to skip this code and go on to the rest, without displaying a canvas. I am using windows, but I am not sure what version of python I'm using.

I was also using 
`from * import tkinter`
before, with relevant changes to the code and i changed it to try and help fix it. It didn't work :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the eventloop at the end:

```
import tkinter
tk=tkinter.Tk()
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

# Enter into eventloop <- this will keep
# running your application, until you exit
tk.mainloop()
```

*Only a personal recommendation: don't use `tk` as a variable name, use `app` or `root` or even `win`/`window`*

Comment: A common mistake is to miss out the () at the end of tk.mainloop, which the latter will return a bound method.