# Instantiating a Canvas in Python : tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Very new to python, just trying to create a Canvas in python using tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
w = Canvas (top , height = 300, width = 300)
```

Yields error: 
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Most of what I saw regarding this issue had to do with running code on a remote machine and not having a place to display the output. I was running this on the online compiler:

https://repl.it/repls/MintyHumongousParentheses

Any insight into this error is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define root for tkinter in Python 3? I'm using an online Python editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436064/how-do-i-define-root-for-tkinter-in-python-3-im-using-an-online-python-editor)

Comment: If where you are executing the code does not contain a display you will not be able to run tkinter. Your online compiler will ending having the same issue as well. Unless it contains some kind of virtual display **(the console window does not count)**.

Answer (score 1):

The tkinter package is a thin object-oriented layer on top of Tcl/Tk. The problem is Tcl can't find the virtual display.

As stovfl pointed out your problem is the online python editor, I don't know witch one you are using, but repl.it is compatible with remi.gui, see example: https://repl.it/@amasad/tictactoe.

I tested your code locally and it didn't work, so I made a few changes:

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
w = Canvas(top, width=300, height=300)
w.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

> [How do I define root for tkinter in Python 3? I'm using an online Python editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436064/how-do-i-define-root-for-tkinter-in-python-3-im-using-an-online-python-editor)
>
> [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html)
>
> [Python Tkinter not working in a .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900919/python-tkinter-not-working-in-a-py-file)